# How can I get the name of the triggering queue at runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a C# WebJob that uses `QueueTrigger` with a custom `INameResolver` to look up queue names from the application settings. This part is working as expected, but now within the method body, I need to know the name of the queue from which the triggering message was received. Ideally, I'd like to just be able to add a specially-named string parameter on my method which would be populated with the triggering queue name by the WebJobs SDK, but the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/) doesn't mention any such bindable parameter.

Is there another way to accomplish this, preferrably without hardcoding the queue name/pattern in two locations (i.e. once in the `QueueTrigger` attribute and again inside the method body) or writing custom string-parsing code to manually invoke my `INameResolver` for `%patterns%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an additional parameter to your function to bind to the queue like so:

```html
public static void MyFunction(
  [QueueTrigger("%name%")] string message,
  [Queue("%name%")] CloudQueue queue)
{
  string queueName = queue.Name;
}
```

An alternative is as you suggested - make your custom INameResolver instance available to your job function (e.g. via DI) and just call resolver.Resolve to get the name.